# Getting error converted oracle index to postgresql

Tags: postgresql-14

we are in the process of migrating oracle to postgresql. during the process we are getting error for the below index.

Oracle Index:
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 (column1||'-A1' ASC) ;

By using schema tool the above index automatically converted into like below. when we try to execute it and getting exception like below.

Postgresql:

CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 USING BTREE (CONCAT_WS() ASC);

Error: ERROR:function concat_ws() does not exist LINE 3: USING BTREE (CONCAT_WS() ASC)

Can someone suggest how to match the oracle index to postgresql: